# Sitecore SPEAK and Javascript

Tags: javascript, sitecore, sitecore-speak-ui

I am trying to replicate what is shown in this [video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2UZWcjqSPc) by Jakob:

I am able to get everything work except the custom Javascript part.

```
define(["sitecore"], function (Sitecore) {
var ListPage = Sitecore.Definitions.App.extend({
    initialized: function () {
      alert('Test');
      }
  });
  return ListPage;
});
```

I even tried to fire Sitecore.app command in sc_debug mode but that is returning  "undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your in Sitecore 7.5 or 8 the app has been moved to Sitecore.Speak.app rather than Sitecore.app

Comment: That solves the problem. I should have mentioned that I am using Sitecore 8.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to add a js script file to your `Page Code` control.

On the `Page Code` Control there is field called `PageCodeScriptFileName` you can add a path to your custom js file there. Then you can add your code above in that js file.

There's more info on this blog post from Martina:

http://mhwelander.net/2014/07/01/speak-for-newbies-part-4-pagecode-and-javascript-libraries/

Comment: Hi, Somehow the javascript is firing up now.. (Sitecore.app still returns undefined though)... But it looks like the application is caching the javascript file.... The changes I am making are not reflecting right away. Any idea about this?